# session.cookie_secure not saving

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, cookie-session

I am using sessions to create temporary file download links. Every time a new request is made, the sessions reset. I found a thread talking about turning on `session.cookie_secure`. But whenever I try setting it to `on` or `1`, it won't save.

Here is what I tried in the php file:

- `ini_set('session.cookie_secure', '1');`
- `@ini_set('session.cookie_secure','1');`
- `@ini_set('session.cookie_secure','On');`

Here is what I tried in the php.ini file:

- `session.cookie_secure = 1`
- `session.cookie_secure = on`

Am I doing something wrong? What should I do to turn on `session.cookie_secure`? Is there something I could do instead of setting `session.cookie_secure`?

Comment: If this configuration is enabled, you should only save the cookie to the client under https. Please confirm that you are using the https protocol?

Comment: Yes, https is enabled and enforced with http being redirected to https.